# Column count by element

Tags: r

how do achieve the equivalent of `awk '{print $1}' /tmp/data | sort | uniq -c` for a particular column in R?

Example:
    cat /tmp/data

```
alama 
alama
alama
bbbb
bbbb
ccc
alama
bbbb
bbbb
```

awk '{print $1}' /tmp/data | sort | uniq -c

> ```
>   1 
>   4 alama
>   4 bbbb
>   1 ccc
> ```

i.e. count of every item in the column.

---

Based on @Joshua's suggestion and my particular needs ...

```
s<-data.frame(table(spam[,1]))
p<-s[s$Freq>=3,]
p[order(p$Freq,decreasing=TRUE ),]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
> set.seed(21)
> Data <- data.frame(V1=sample(letters[1:5],20,TRUE))
> length(unique(Data[,1]))
[1] 5
```

---

Based on your updated question -- assuming data is in `x`:

```
> table(x)
x
alama  bbbb   ccc 
    4     4     1 
> data.frame(table(x))
      x Freq
1 alama    4
2  bbbb    4
3   ccc    1
```

Comment: ... or use `nlevels` if it is a factor.

Comment: @Richie But if factor has missing levels then will be difference.

Comment: @Marek: `nlevels(x[, drop=TRUE])` in that case.

Comment: Edited the question so as clarify the question.

Comment: nice :) .... just what I needed to this was `s<-data.frame(table(spam[,1]))
p<-s[s$Freq>=3,]
p[order(p$Freq,decreasing=TRUE ),]`